# linq any function vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, any

I have this code and it works as excepted:

```
            For i = 0 To _SelectedFields.Count - 1
                For j = 0 To _SelectedFields(i).DataFields.Count - 1
                    For k = 0 To _Aggregations.Count - 1
                        If Not _Aggregations(k).AggregatedExpr.Contains(_SelectedFields(i).DataFields(j).FieldName) Then
                            If Not FieldInGroupBy.Contains(_SelectedFields(i).DataFields(j).FieldName) Then
                                MessageBox.Show("Missing selected field '" & _SelectedFields(i).DataFields(j).FieldName & "' at GROUP BY.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                                Exit Sub
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            Next
```

I though, I make it with linq:

```
    If Not _SelectedFields.Any(Function(SelectedField) SelectedField.DataFields.Any(Function(DataField)
                                                                                        If Not _Aggregations.Any(Function(Aggregation) Aggregation.AggregatedExpr.Contains(DataField.FieldName)) Then
                                                                                            Return FieldInGroupBy.Contains(DataField.FieldName)
                                                                                        Else
                                                                                            Return True
                                                                                        End If
                                                                                    End Function)) Then
        MsgBox("error")
    End If
```

In my opinion, the above is the same as the working one. But it doesn't work as intended.

Have you any ideas, why this doesn't work?

Comment: "it doesn't work as intended" doesn't give us any information as to what it *does* do...

Comment: I mean, the messagebox should be showing as it does in the first solution. Background: there are aggregations. Each aggregation contains an aggregated expression. Then I have selected fields. Each selected fields has datafields. Each datafield has a field name. As you see, I check, whether this field name is in any of the aggregated expressions. If not, then I check, whether this field name is in the FieldInGroupBy, which is a simple list of strings. As you see to do this, I iterate trough the collections. But it could be doing with the any function too, I think.

Comment: All of this should be in your question, not in comments... and ideally you should provide a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first bit of code is your intended behaviour then I think this suffices:

```
Dim query = _
    From sf In _SelectedFields _
    From df In sf.DataFields _
    From ag In _Aggregations _
    Where Not ag.AggregatedExpr.Contains(df.FieldName) _
    Where Not FieldInGroupBy.Contains(df.FieldName) _
    Select df.FieldName

For Each x in query
    MessageBox.Show( _
        "Missing selected field '" & x & "' at GROUP BY.", _
        "", _
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Exit Sub
Next
```